# Automatic publicPath is not supported in this browser

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron, webpack-5

In a Electron-React-Typescript app I'm getting this error:

`Automatic publicPath is not supported in this browser`

devDependencies in package.json :

```
"css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.0",
"electron": "^11.2.3",
"typescript": "^4.1.5",
"webpack": "^5.21.2",
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.4.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
```

Following the indications found here: [Webpack5 Automatic publicPath is not supported in this browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64294706/webpack5-automatic-publicpath-is-not-supported-in-this-browser/66212720#66212720)

webpack.rules.config.js :

```
// Images Loader
test: /\.(gif|jpe?g|tiff|png|webp|bmp)$/,
use: [
  {
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      //publicPath: '',
      publicPath: inDev ? 'images' : './main_window/images',
      outputPath: inDev ? 'images' : './main_window/images',
    },
  },
```

I tried both to set the publicPath to empty and to fill with the value of outputPath.  also removed mini-css-extract-plugin. But none of these worked.

Any suggestions?