# Cypress publicPath not supported with percy and nock

Tags: node.js, cypress, webpack-5, nock, percy

I'm getting an issue where I am trying to add [percy](https://percy.io/) to my [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) tests using [nock](https://github.com/nock/nock) and webpack 5.   Based on a solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64715069), I tried to set the `publicPath` to an empty string, but with no success. The error message I get is

> The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.
>
> > Automatic publicPath is not supported in this browser
>
> When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code
> it will automatically fail the current test.
>
> Cypress could not associate this error to any specific test.
>
> We dynamically generated a new test to display this failure

```
.../webpack/runtime/publicPath:14:1
  // When supporting browsers where an automatic publicPath is not supported you must specify an output.publicPath manually via configuration
  // or pass an empty string ("") and set the __webpack_public_path__ variable from your code to use your own logic.
  if (!scriptUrl) throw new Error("Automatic publicPath is not supported in this browser");
      ^
    scriptUrl = scriptUrl.replace(/#.*$/, "").replace(/\?.*$/, "").replace(/\/[^\/]+$/, "/");
    __webpack_require__.p = scriptUrl;
```

In my `cypress/plugins/webpack.config.js` file, I have the following.

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: { extensions: ['.ts', '.js'], fallback: { http: false } },
  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      },
    ],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          transpileOnly: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

In my `cypress/plugins/index.js`, I have the following.

```
const nock = require('nock');
const http = require('http');
const next = require('next');
const webpackPreprocessor = require('@cypress/webpack-preprocessor');

module.exports = async (on, config) => {
  const app = next({ dev: true });
  const handleNextRequests = app.getRequestHandler();
  await app.prepare();

  const customServer = new http.Server(async (req, res) => {
    return handleNextRequests(req, res);
  });

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    customServer.listen(3000, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }

      resolve();
    });
  });

  on('task', {
    clearNock() {
      nock.restore();
      nock.cleanAll();

      return null;
    },

    async nock({ hostname, method, path, statusCode, body }) {
      nock.activate();

      // add one-time network stub like
      method = method.toLowerCase();
      nock(hostname)[method](path).reply(statusCode, body);

      return null;
    },
  });

  const options = {
    webpackOptions: require('./webpack.config'),
    watchOptions: {},
  };

  on('file:preprocessor', webpackPreprocessor(options));

  return config;
};
```

How can I configure the `publicPath` properly?